# Where can I find "Nemesis II", the sequel to "Nemesis", an old CP/M game?

Tags: software, cp-m

In 1981, the "[Nemesis](http://www.mocagh.org/loadpage.php?getgame=nemesis)" game was released for CP/M-based machines by Super Soft Inc., with the author attribution of Michael A. Pagels and Michael Q Hiller, and artist attribution of Diana J. Bush. According to the included documentation, a second version "Nemesis II" was created in 1982, the notable new feature being LAN multi-player support.

For those not familiar, Nemesis is a text-based CRPG dungeon-crawler rogue-like, based on of the works of Tolkien in general, and D&D specifically; there was also a level editor called "Dungeon Master" though most releases of the game did not include the "Dungeon Master" component. This game was unique for it's real-time game play and full-screen map exploration characteristics.

I am looking for a means of acquiring a verified working copy of Nemesis II.

Comment: For anyone who wants to try out the first Nemesis, you can download it from and play it with [z80pack](http://www.autometer.de/unix4fun/z80pack/#download) (including the Dungeon Master component). Make sure to use the `-f 4` to set emulation speed to 4 MHz (or lower), or it will be way too fast.

Comment: Does that version have the DM manual as well? If not, it can be found at the link I provided. Thanks for the link to a version of the software.

Comment: After browsing the manual, I also suspect that possibly Nemesis II was never released, and there was just a work-in-progress version that was playtested by the Nemesis user group members. At least that's what I read into the description. So unless you find one of those user group members, and he has kept a copy, it will be probably really difficult to find a working copy.

Comment: I have attempted to contact one of the original programmers that I found online, but have received no reply yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like one of the original authors chimed in on a USENET thread (comp.os.cpm):

> I'm Michael Pagels, one of the two authors.  We had a great time
>   writing this game, and it helped pay for grad school.  Of course, we
>   had to change the name of Dungeon Master; something pesky about
>   copyrights!  We never got to Nemesis II, but we did write one of the
>   first multi-player games for MP/M or serially linked CP/M machines
>   called StarJump.  I never continued in the games business, but I've
>   continued innovating in the computer industry.
>
> Michael

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.os.cpm/mfTdhZttbTo

**There is no copy to find** as it does not appear they ever completed the planned game.

However, the multi-player game "StarJump" may be of interest, given you can find an archive copy.